# Percentage question on playing a game

Tags: probability

I was doing some past papers of AMC when I got stuck on this question:

Two people were playing a video game. One morning each of them won 70% of their games. That afternoon, they played the same number of games as each other and each won them all. One of the player's winning percentage for the day rose to 85%, while the other player's winning percentage rose to 90%. What is the minimum possible total number of games that they could've played that morning?

I couldn't find an efficient method of working out the solution. By trial and error I found out that they could have played a minimum of 30 games in total, (10 for one and 20 for the other) and by each winning 20 more games, the required result is achieved. I'm sure there's another much more efficient method other than trial and error

Comment: For word problems, define variables and write equations to reflect what you know.  Let $x$ be the number of games they played in the afternoon.  Let $a$ be the number of games the first won in the morning and $b$ the number of games the second won in the morning.  Can you write some equations? -1 You should get two equations in three unknowns, but you know the variables are integers.  Factors are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They clearly each played a multiple of $10$ games in the morning and a multiple of $10$ (or of $20$ but that is a multiple of $10$) games in total, so a multiple of $10$ games in the afternoon.

Let's suppose the first player played $10a$ games in the morning and $10b$ in the afternoon.  You know $7a+10b=8.5(a+b)$ so $a=b$ and the smallest positive integer solution is $a=1,b=1$.  As a check this gives $7/10$ games won in the morning, $10/10$ in the afternoon and $17/20$ overall

Let's suppose the second player played $10c$ games in the morning and $10c$ in the afternoon.  You know $7c+10d=9(c+d)$ so $2c=d$ and the smallest positive integer solution is $c=1,d=2$.  As a check this gives $7/10$ games won in the morning, $20/20$ in the afternoon and $27/30$ overall

To me this suggests $10+10$ games played in the morning and $20+30=50$ overall